# TestNG - skip test that uses groups in the annotation

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured

I cannot figure out how to skip tests from execution if they have the parameter group="some" and there are executed several tests with/without group definition from testNG.xml file.

Let me put together what I have.

```
@Test
public void shouldBeStatusCodeEqualTo200WhenGetRequestPerformed() {
    req.get().then().statusCode(200).log().ifValidationFails();
    System.out.println(req.get().getBody().asString());
    System.out.println("Status code is 200");
}

@Test(dataProvider = "queryParmsAccountSummaryData", dataProviderClass = AccountSummaryQueryStringsDataProvider.class, groups = "queryStringRequired")
public void shouldBeStatusCodeEqualTo200WhenGetRequestWithQueryStringParmPerformed(Map<String, String> queryStringParms) {
    req.params(queryStringParms);
    req.given().when().get().then().statusCode(200);
    System.out.println(req.get().getBody().asString());
    System.out.println("Status code is 200");
```

TestNG.xml

```
<test thread-count="5" name="GetAccountSummaryByCompany" parallel="classes">
    <parameter name="accountSummaryByCompany" value="th/rfff/ee" />
    <parameter name="customerCode" value="123" />
    <parameter name="countryCode" value="NOS" />

    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="queryStringRequired" />
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes>
        <class
            name="accMgn.accountSummaryByCompany.GetAccountSummaryByCompany" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test thread-count="5" name="GetLegalEntity" parallel="classes" enabled="true">
    <parameter name="legalEntity" value="fe/juy/fds" />


    <classes>
        <class name="accMgn.legalEntity.GetLegalEntity" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

If I run the TestNG.xml it executes both tests. Even if the group is not defined in TestNG.xml. How to make it skipped?

Comment: I forgot to put, that I do not want to use exclude in the XML. Is it possible to do it in another way?

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IAnnotationTransformer` and override the `transform` method as per your need.

**Example:**

```
public class AnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transform (final ITestAnnotation annotation, final Class testClass, final Constructor testConstructor,
            final Method testMethod) {
        String [] groups = annotation.getGroups ();
        for (String group : groups) {
            if (group.equals ("some")) {
                annotation.setEnabled (false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the listener in your `testng.xml` file in `listener` block as shown below:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="your.package.YourListenerClass" />
</listeners>
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try.

Comment: Did my answer helped? There's no update about this for quite a while.